# How to configure accept_local through system calls in C

Tags: c, linux-kernel, network-programming, system-calls, ioctl

I want to configure variable accept_local in /proc/sys/net/ipv4// dynamically. Instead of using file operation, is there any system call that I can use to configure this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing values to files *is* syscalls, so, if you want to achieve that through Linux syscalls:

- `fd = open("/proc/sys/net/ipv4/accept_local", O_WRONLY)` that file (first syscall)
- `write(fd, "1",  1)` to that (second syscall)
- `close(fd)` the file handle (third syscall).

Voila, network configuration done through three syscalls.

PS: Your question reeks very much of the famous [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: What I am asking is, can we use sysctl calls to update the value. If I can use it, how to direct it to a particular interface. I couldn't find any example that uses sysctl with interface

Comment: Please carefully read my answer. These are exactly the syscalls that linux has for this kind of task. There's, unless you write a kernel module to implement those somehow, no others, as far as I know. I don't see why there *should* be any other syscalls. Having multiple ways of doing the same thing is not a good feature for a kernel, so you'd avoid that.

Comment: also, **read** about the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info); you're still not explaining *why* you'd do that, instead of just going through sysfs as usual. You're probably trying to solve something and think this is the solution, but anyone with more experience is a bit confounded by what you're trying to do! So, explain what you want to build, rather than what you want to immediately do (as that makes little sense).

Comment: Ended up using system("echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/F4247/accept_local")

Comment: I found packets being dropped from the Kernel IP stack, as the source address is same as the interface IP. Wanted to disable source check for such scenarios. I found we can do it by changing accept_local.

Comment: why!?!? guess what echo 1> ... essentially does? Exactly, `open` that file, `write` to it, and `close` it. Congrats, you found the least clever way of doing this.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Using `system("echo 1 > ...")` is good choice if one doesn't bother about perfomance and error handling, because it occupies a **single line of code** instead of 3 lines `open`-`write`-`close`. But otherwise, I agree with you. Also, one may think about writting into `/proc` as using **kernel's interface**: system calls are part of kernel's interface, but `proc` filesystem is part of kernel's interface too.

Answer (score -1):

This can definitely help you [sysctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysctl.2.html)

Comment: From your very link (emphasis mine):
       *Glibc does not provide a wrapper for this system call; call it using
       syscall(2).  Or rather...  **don't call it**: use of this system call has
       long been discouraged, and it is so unloved that it is likely to
       disappear in a future kernel version.  Since Linux 2.6.24, uses of
       this system call result in warnings in the kernel log.  **Remove it
       from your programs now**; **use the /proc/sys interface instead**.*

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: @EricPostpischil if an external resource contains exactly what you're looking for, why should I write hundreds of words?

Comment: @tano: You would write at least some of them, and refer to the external resource as containing more information. Think about link becomes dead: in that case your answer would be **useless**, and this is bad.

Comment: @tano: External sources vanish, and other reasons are discussed in the link I pointed you to. Why are you asking me for information that is in the link I pointed you to?